# If conditions in gitlab-ci.yml via shell-runner

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Colleagues! Such question, whether it is possible to use if conditions via shell-runner on a remote server? Here is a test gitlab-ci.yml:

```
world_branch:
  variables: 
    dir: "/home/TATATA"
  environment: staging
  script:
  - ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.0.12 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
      'if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
          rm -r $dir && mkdir $dir
          fi'
       "
  - rsync -avz --delete-after --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitlab-ci.yml" . root@192.168.0.12:/home/TATATA
  only: 
   - world
```

After running the job, get the next error:

```
bash: if [[ -d /home/TATATA ]] rm -r /home/TATATA && mkdir /home/TATATA fi: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

It was fixed only in this way:

```
- ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
       if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
         rm -r $dir && mkdir $dir;
       fi
       "
```

I mean, than you need to put after the shell command ;

For constructions where the shell commands are two or more, you just need to add to the end of each one again ;

For example:

```
- ssh root@192.168.0.12 "
     if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]; then
        mkdir $dir;
        mkdir $dir/test;
     fi
     "
```